# Will vs. will later

Tags: sentence-meaning

Let's say a small amount of vinegar accidentally spattered on your girlfriend's clothes. And you say:

> You should wash it now with soap, because it **will** smell.

Vs.

> You should wash it now with soap, because it **will** smell **later.**

What is the difference between the two? Is the second sentence redundant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having difficulty with these is that there is an implicit word in there. Try it this way.

You should wash it now with soap, because *otherwise* it will smell.

You should wash it now with soap, because *otherwise* it will smell later.

Really what you are trying to say is that it will smell if it is not washed. So the first version is preferable. You don't need to pair up now and later.

Comment: Hello thx for the help, but, can you tell me why do I have to omit the ''later''?

Comment: Because it will smell now and later if it is not washed. It won't just start smelling at some time in the future, it smells now.

Answer (score 0):

I like the word 'or' to help with these.

> You should wash it now with soap, or it will smell
>
> You should wash it now with soap, or it will keep smelling.
>
> You should wash it now with soap, or it will smell later.